# Run graphical program without rendering graphics

Tags: debian, graphics, opengl, gtk3

I would like to run a 3d game, but I wouldn't like to spent time rendering it. The idea would be that as I'm not limited by the rendering, I could run simulations a lot faster.

I'm pretty sure that at some point in the runtime, the programs tells the system what it would like to render, and I want to intercept this to not render, and also extract the data.

Is there anyway that this is possible?